# I dont know why I cant download this image from: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/d2/Juventus_Turin.svg

Tags: swift, xcode, networking

I can download images just fine but that URL dont work, is there a known problem with that type of URL?
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/d2/Juventus_Turin.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download like this:

- Create WKWebView
- Connect outlet
- Conform WKUIDelegate in your controller
- Create request with your wiki link
- Set webView uiDelegate to self
- Load from request

[image: Example Code]

**You should configure content for UI :)**
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Svg images doesn't get directly supported in iOS apps. you simply need to add on a third party pod extension in order to use the svg images in app. 
For example : https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG

Try using this PocketSVG.

Comment: Ok, but isn't that for manipulating the response? the thing is that i don't get any response from the url